# EM Algorithm for Kalman Filters

Tags: expectation-maximization, graphical-model, kalman-filter, latent-variable

Say I have the following dynamical system with unknown covariances for $w,v$.
$$
z_n = Az_{n-1}+w\\
x_n = Bz_n +v
$$

where $w \sim \mathcal{N}(0,Q)$ and $v \sim \mathcal{N}(0,R)$.

I want to apply the EM algorithm to estimate the covariance matrices $Q$ and $R$ in an online fashion.

First, we can apply the forward algorithm (Kalman Filter) to find $p(z_n |x^n) \sim \mathcal{N}(z_{n|n}, P_{n|n})$.

The general EM algorithm is as follows:

We need to maximize the lower bound  with respect to $q(z_n)$. This is the E-step
$$
\text{log}\ p(x^n|\theta) \ge \int q(z_n) \text{log} \ \frac{p(x^n,z_n|\theta)}{q(z_n)} dz_n
$$

The maximization is found for $q^*(z_n) = p(z_n|x^n,\theta)$.

Next, we then need to maximize the above expectation integral over $\theta$ to find the parameter update.

$$
\hat{\theta} =\text{argmax}_{\theta}\int q^*(z_n) \text{log} \ \frac{p(x^n,z_n|\theta)}{q^*(z_n)} dz_n $$

SInce we maximize over $\theta$, this simplifies to

$$
= \text{argmax}_{\theta} \int q^*(z_n) \text{log} \ p(x^n, z_n |\theta) dz_n
$$

Im stuck here, I don't think we know the joint $p(x^n, z_n |\theta)$ from the Kalman filter.

Is there a nice closed form solution for estimating the parameter update like in the GMM case?

Comment: Not sure what it meant by 'nice closed form solution' here but this is no known closed form solutions for EM/Kalman Filters in generic form, it is a numerical optimisation problem. MARSS R package provides a derivation of joint log-likelihood function https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/EMDerivation.pdf See Eq 6 there and EM algorithm section.

Comment: The paper was exactly what I needed. Thanks.